# Possible to build PySide on Windows with MinGW?

Tags: qt, cmake, mingw, pyside

I checked http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building_PySide_on_Windows and seems it shows only Visual Studio is used to build PySide on Windows. Does that mean Visual Studio is the only choice? Is it possible to use MinGW? If it's possible, can anyone kindly show me how? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that adding support for building PySide with MinGW is a work in progress. See [here](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/PYSIDE-113?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel)